# Realtek RTS5138 Card Reader not working

Tags: 14.04, drivers, realtek, card-reader

I have a Dell N5110 laptop with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on it. My internal card reader is a Realtek RTS5138 is not working (when I plug-in an SD card nothing happens).

I tried [this solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/102341/how-would-you-install-the-rts5139-card-reader-driver-for-use-on-fedora-19/102348#102348) (although it is for Realtek rts5139 and I found an rts5139 module on my system) but it didn't work.

When I plug in and SD card in the internal card reader it appears in the `lsusb` output:

```
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0bda:0138 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5138 Card Reader Controller
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0c45:6441 Microdia 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0cf3:3005 Atheros Communications, Inc. AR3011 Bluetooth
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: I don't see any mention of a card reader in the output of `lsusb`. If it's USB, is it plugged in and enabled? Otherwise it might be connected directly to PCI. Try finding it wit `lspci`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, the card reader entry appears in lsusb output when I plug in an SD card in the internal card reader

Comment: Ok, what's the output of `sudo dmesg` and `lsblk` just after you put a memory card in the reader?

Comment: I plugged in the SD card in the reader and:
dmseg: http://pastebin.com/0pGUu7KR 
lsblk: http://pastebin.com/8prZgg0k
Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Installing the package 'exfat-fuse' could solve the problem.

If the card reader is being detected correctly, as it seems it was from the original poster's logs, then perhaps the card was formatted with a filesystem such as 'exfat' for which support hasn't yet been installed. This has solved similar issues for me.